# Ice-faces: avoid data-table value caching at server level

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, weblogic, icefaces

I am new to JSF and ICE faces,

Below are the preface to my problem.

**fxtext - Backing bean variable name in xhtml**

**fxtext.textList - is populated in the data table**

Based on

> valueChangeListener="#{fxtext.gettextDetailsBytype}

data is populated dynamically in data table.

The data table in below xhtml

**My Xhtml file**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:wm="http://www.test.com/wm">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/nav.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="bodycontent">
            <ice:panelGroup timestamp="#{fxtext.timestampNew}">
             <ice:outputStyle href="#{contextpath}/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <ice:form id="managetextForm">
                    <div class="shadow_container">
                        <!--border-->
                        <div class="color_container_blue">
                            <ui:include src="../fxtextadmin/fxtextadmin_sub_nav.xhtml">
                                <ui:param name="selectedSubTab" value="fxsearch" />
                            </ui:include>
                            <!--content-->
                            <div class="content_container">

                                <div class="module" style="width: 100% !important">
                                    <div class="module_head" style="width: 100% !important;">
                                        <h2>Manage Fx text Details</h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="module_body" rendered="#{not empty fxtext.textRow}">
                                        <ice:outputText rendered="#{not empty fxtext.errorMessage}" styleClass="redFontError">
                                            #{fxtext.errorMessage}
                                        </ice:outputText>
                                        <ice:messages errorClass="redFontError"></ice:messages>
                                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                                        <div class="fieldrow">
                                            <span class="label width30per">Fx ID : #{fxtext.textRow.fxtextId}</span>
                                            <span class="label width70per">Fx Name : #{fxtext.textRow.name}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                                        <div class="fieldrow">
                                            <span class="label width200">#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.type.label']}</span>
                                            <div class="space5"></div>
                                            <ice:selectOneMenu styleClass="width200" valueChangeListener="#{fxtext.gettextDetailsBytype}"
                                                value="#{fxtext.type}" immediate="true" id="typeselect" partialSubmit="true">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{fxtext.typeList}"></f:selectItems>
                                            </ice:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>

                                        <ice:dataTable value="#{fxtext.textList}" id="textValue"
                                            var="textRow" width="100%" varStatus="vs" styleClass="fxtexttab"
                                            headerClasses="lightgreyheader,lightgreyheader" rendered="#{not empty fxtext.textList}">
                                            <ice:column>
                                                <div class="spacer"></div>
                                                <div class="fieldrow">
                                                    <span class="label margin5px" style="width: 25%">#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.starttime.label']}</span>
                                                    <span class="label margin5px" style="width: 25%">#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.endtime.label']}</span>
                                                    <span class="label margin5px" style="width: 25%">#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.text.label']}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fieldrow">
                                                    <ice:inputText styleClass="width200 margin13px" value="#{textRow.startTime}" maxlength="4"/>
                                                    <ice:inputText styleClass="width200 margin13px" value="#{textRow.endTime}" maxlength="4"/>
                                                    <ice:inputText styleClass="width200 margin13px" value="#{textRow.textValue}" maxlength="4"/>
                                                    <ice:commandLink action="#{fxtext.deletetextInterval}" 
                                                        immeditate="true" styleClass="orange_big" id="delete" title="Delete">
                                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{fxtext.removetext}" value="#{textRow}"/>
                                                        <span>#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.action.delete.label']}</span>
                                                    </ice:commandLink>
                                                    <ice:commandLink action="#{fxtext.addOrUpdatetextInterval}" 
                                                        immeditate="true" styleClass="orange_big" id="save" title="Save" 
                                                        rendered="#{!vs.last}">
                                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{fxtext.addtext}" value="#{textRow}"/>
                                                        <span>#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.action.add.label']}</span>
                                                    </ice:commandLink>
                                                    <ice:commandLink action="#{fxtext.addOrUpdatetextInterval}" 
                                                        immeditate="true" styleClass="orange_big" id="save_last" title="Save" 
                                                        rendered="#{vs.last}">
                                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{fxtext.addtext}" value="#{textRow}"/>
                                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{fxtext.addMoreEnabled}" value="true"/>
                                                        <span>#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.action.add.label']}</span>
                                                    </ice:commandLink>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="spacer"></div>
                                            </ice:column>
                                        </ice:dataTable>
                                        <ice:outputText rendered="#{empty fxtext.textList}">
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.no.text.entry.message']}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </ice:outputText>                                       
                                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                                        <ice:panelGroup styleClass="buttonwrapper_left" rendered="#{(wm:length(fxtext.textList) lt 25) and not empty fxtext.textRow}">
                                            <ice:commandLink  
                                                styleClass="orange_big" action="#{fxtext.addMoretextInterval}" immeditate="true" 
                                                id="addmorebuttonenabled" rendered="#{fxtext.addMoreEnabled}">
                                                <span>#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.action.addmore.label']}</span>
                                            </ice:commandLink>
                                            <ice:commandLink id="addmorebuttondisabled"
                                                styleClass="grey disabled" onclick="return false;" rendered="#{!fxtext.addMoreEnabled}">
                                                <span>#{resources['fxtextadmin.fxtext.action.addmore.label']}</span>
                                            </ice:commandLink>
                                        </ice:panelGroup>
                                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ice:form>
            </ice:panelGroup>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**In my java backing bean file,**

```
public void gettextDetailsBytype(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Loging.debug(" Method Start - selected " + event.getNewValue());
        errorMessage = "";
        if(event.getNewValue() != null) {
            originaltextList = myService.getTextValues(fiId, (String)event.getNewValue());
            textList.clear();
            textList.addAll(originalThrottleList);
            for(text t :textList){
                CMessageLog.getInstance().debug("Type" + event.getNewValue() + " "+t.getStartTime()+ " "+t.getEndTime()+ " "+t.gettextValue());
            }
            addMoreEnabled = true;
        }
        Loging.debug("  Method End");
    }
```

**Now My problem is**

When  values in **fxtext.textList** are changed, It is not reflecting in my Data-table in UI.

I mean, If there are values of list (1,2,3,4,6) initially in fxtext.textList
when change listener is triggered , assume now fxtext.textList has values (5,8).
But the data-table displays (1,2). But logging the data in bean has correct values (5,8)

> Note it retains the size of the list but values are not changed

**Is there any attributes or tags has to be added to disable cache in server?**
Because in browser network console I can see it returns wrong data(cached data) from server.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Note:**
I am using list(1,2,3,4,5..) literally to explain below fields.

```
value="#{textRow.startTime}"
value="#{textRow.endTime}" 
value="#{textRow.textValue}"
```

Comment: I don't think anyone has any ide of what you are asking. I at least have no clue... Please improve your question

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the reply , the problem was due to improper re initialisation of **fxtext.textList**  It got solved once proerly handled.

Comment: It has nothing to do with server cache!